# Javascript print JS value and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I'm using a script to drag images on my website, the images have a position that I want to store in a MySQL database with PHP. My problem is that I don't know how to print the javascript position values so that I can insert it into the database. Everything else works fine. The guide I'm following is this: http://draggabilly.desandro.com/ and you can look at the very last example where the positions are tracked and stored in a variable. Thanks in advance.

```
 <div id="house_wall1">
            <img src="x" class="draggie" style="position:relative; left:200px;">
            <img src="x" class="draggie" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="x" class="draggie" style="position:relative;">


            <!--Cypyrights and many thanks to http://desandro.mit-license.org for element movements -->

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js"></script>


            <script>
    ( function() {
      var container = document.querySelector('#house_wall1');
      var elems = container.querySelectorAll('.draggie');
      for ( var i=0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        new Draggabilly( elem, {
      containment: true,
      });
     }
   })();


function onDragMove( instance, event, pointer ) {
  console.log( 'dragMove on ' + event.type +
    pointer.pageX + ', ' + pointer.pageY +
    ' position at ' + instance.position.x + ', ' + instance.position.y );

}
// bind event listener
draggie.on( 'dragMove', onDragMove );
// un-bind event listener
draggie.off( 'dragMove', onDragMove );
// return true to trigger an event listener just once
draggie.once( 'dragMove', function() {
return true;

});



 </script>

    </div>
```

UPDATE:
Trying to get ajax to parse the value and print it to make sure it works:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            dragEnd: true
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","post.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: why do you want to print the js value for inserting into the database?

Comment: I don't know how to reach the value, I need to get it into the database in order for the server to remember what position the elements were last dragged to. I don't know how I can get the values out. Like, what values is it? Lol thx

Comment: you could pass the values from `onDragMove` to another function which makes an ajax call

Comment: yeah and then the ajax call should be called once the image is released. I just have no idea how to code this in Javascript

Comment: suggest you do some reading . http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: @anurupr I already know a little ajax but my problem is that I know barely anything about javascript, if you take a look above, how would I parse the Javascript value so that it can be printed? in the post.php I just have an echo statement to echo the position

Comment: in `xmlhttp.send()` pass the position values as a string and process it in `post.php`

Comment: you should consider using jquery for this.